# Update ember 2.6.2 to 2.7.0 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eachAttribute' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

- ember@2.6.2 to ember@2.7.0
- ember-data@2.9.0 (however same error when running under 2.5.x)

The following was worked fine before the update.

Getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eachAttribute' of undefined`

I am reloading a model

`this.modelFor('admin').get('ssoApplicationSubscriptions').reload();`

When it starts executing the `eachAttribute` loop I get the error. Interestingly the constructor is undefined at this point.

[image]

Here are the model definitions

```
// Organisation
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
});

// Institution Organisation
export default Organisation.extend({
  ssoApplicationSubscriptions: hasMany('sso-application-subscription', { polymorphic: true })
});
```

I am using the JSONAPIAdapter/Serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue with this one and it came down to me using the constructor to get the model name of the polymorphic model. 
in my case I have emails and emails belong to a promotion, which is polymorphic so it looked like this:

`{{email.promotion.content.constructor.modelName}}`

and what I did to change it was this:
I added `promotion_type: DS.attr("string")` to my `Email` Model

and change the template to use that attr: `{{email.promotion_type}}`

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the issue.  I have the following `selectedOrganisation.constructor.modelName` in a templates, commenting this out has resolved the issue. However, now I am getting another issue relating to the `this.constructor` on an ember-data model being `undefined`. WiIll need to investigate further.